# JSP - adding one form param that is not on the modelAttribute

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a form that maps student information for searching.

I want to add the course number as a search criteria as well. The course number relates to the student through the enrolment.

Since the course number doesn't exist on the Student class, by sending only the student as modelAttribute won't send the course number to the controller.

So I was wondering what would be the best way to send the course number to the controller as well.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

snippet JSP file:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/tar/sisStudentSearch"
    commandName="student">
    <table class ="layoutBodyTable border">
        //...
                            <td class="label_r">First Name:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="100" size="50" /></td>
                            <td class="label_r">Surname:</td>
                            <td><input type="text"  name="familyName" maxlength="100" size="50" /></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label_r"  alt="Gender">Gender:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="sexCode" maxlength="1" size="1" /></td>
                            <td class="label_r"  alt="Date of birth">Date of Birth:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" maxlength="10" size="10" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label_r">College No:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" maxlength="3" size="3" /></td>
                            <td class="label_r">Course No:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="courseNo" name="enrolments.courseNo" maxlength="5" size="5" />
                            //...
</form:form>
```

Snippet controller:

```
public class StudentSearchController {

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/sisStudentSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView searchStudents(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student,
            Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request) {

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        // StudentService userService = new StudentService();
        Logger.getLogger(StudentSearchController.class).info("Student id received as parameter: " + student.getStudentNo());


            students = studentService.findStudents(student);        
            if (students!= null && !students.isEmpty()){
                Logger.getLogger(StudentSearchController.class).info("Students found ! First name: " + students.get(0).getFirstName());
            }
        }
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("sisStudent");
        modelAndView.addObject("students", students);
        return modelAndView;

    }   

}
```

Comment: it must be being sent, try reading in your controller as `request.getParameter("courseNo");`

Comment: Its name that's sent, not id, so it would be `request.getParameter("enrolments.courseNo");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an accustomed Models, I hope you are not using your entities as Model Object cause that's not a good practice:

```
public class StudentModel{
    private String name;
    //other attributes
    private String courseId;
    // GETTERS and SETTERS for all the fields
}
```

PS: you can use `@Max` , `@Min` as validation on your model attributes.

your controller :

```
public class StudentSearchController {

     @Autowired
     StudentService studentService;


     // added this assuming that you need courses from database
     @Autowired
     CourseService courseService;
     StudentModel studentmodel;

      @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView init() {
               studentmodel = new StudentModel();
               ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
               //assuming that your seach page is named studentpage
               List<Course> courses  = courseService.findCourses(..);
               modelAndView.addObject("student", studentmodel );  
               modelAndView.addObject("courses", courses);  
               //OR
               modelAndView.addObject("enrolments",courseService.findTheCourseYouNeed(..));
               // any other logic
       return modelAndView;
       }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/sisStudentSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView searchStudents(@ModelAttribute("student") StudentModel student,
                    Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request) {
                //here you can acess your courseNumber from StudentModel student
               // Apply you logic by calling the studentService filter method that gets attributs from the model
                ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("sisStudent");
                modelAndView.addObject("students", students);
                return modelAndView;

     }   
}
```

in your JSP :

assign the value of your input to courseNo, or use select and option by the value of courseId

```
<td><input type="text" id="courseNo" name="courseId" value="${enrolments.courseNo}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ShadowRay. I think this explains a lot of issues I was having in my mappings. Actually, I posted this question exactly because I had a feeling something was wrong and you just got it by answering that I should not map my entities as model. That is exactly what I was understanding that should be done when I was reading about Spring MVC. I need to read my material again and check why I got such misunderstanding. Thanks again!

Comment: you welcome :) as for material i would recommend spring in action third edition, it is a fine book